# One column not showing up when using active scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using active scaffold on my website. Recently I added a new table and one of the columns is not showing up when accessing the application. Can anyone help me in debugging this? I have been stuck with this for the past two days.

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Comment: What does your schema look like? Did you add the new column in a separate migration after generating your initial scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two tables with same column name. Since I was including all helpers in my application controller the helper method corresponding to a column of the first table was always getting invoked instead of the helper method corresponding to the column in  my new table.

Thanks,
SIvakumar.